# how much free space do I need for db2 backup file?

Tags: backup, db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5

I have a db2 database on Linux (DB2 10.5 fp08).
Now I would like to backup it, before backup I can get the database size with `db2 "call GET_DBSIZE_INFO (?,?,?,0)"`
For example it is 6 GB.

I know if the backup location has >6 GB free space is Ok for this backup.

But do you know if there is any offical documents/post about this.
What is the best higher free space for this kind of backup?

Comment: [GET_DBSIZE_INFO procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0011863.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backup image contains only used extents, so it might be substantially smaller than the sum of tablespace sizes, depending on the tablespaces' types and their physical properties.

On the other hand, in DB2 10.5 the backup image will by default include log files that are modified during the backup, so depending on how active the database is during the backup you may need to include the log sizes into your calculation.

Finally, the backup image can be compressed. Compression ratio is impossible to estimate in advance.

As a result, you can only estimate the upper limit for free space required to store the backup image, which would be the sum total of the current tablespace sizes plus the size of included log files plus the backup image header.

See also [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586896/what-affects-db2-restored-database-size).